# Не могу придумать как использовать данный метод для сравнения непримитивнх объектов класса

Tags: java, объекты, generics

Метод:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int F(T[] anArray, T elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T e : anArray)
        if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
            ++count;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: а какая цель? вы хотите посчитать сколько раз объект elem содержится в коллекции? тогда вам нужен метод equals, а не compareTo

Comment: Если вам нужно посчитать как часто встречаются элементы, можете использовать стрим ``` Map<T, Long> = Arrays.asStrem(array).filter(a - > a>0).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity, count()) ; ````